# Counting specific 3-word-phrases in file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-count

I tried to find and count specific 3-word-phrases in txt files by using this code:

```
phrases = ['hi there you','eat sausage bread', ...]

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for word in phrases:
        contents = f.read()
        count = contents.count('word')
        print(word, count)
```

Python lists me every phrase, but it doesn't count it accurately. Instead the 1st phrase is always 63 and any of the following are 0. As I have more than 100 phrases and also lot's of different files it would be a waste of time to count any phrase on its own (which btw works with this script). Maybe someone could clear my obvious mistake or knows a possible solutions, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: What is `pro2`? And your indentation seems off too...

Comment: Can you show a bit of your text file?

Comment: "pro2" should be "phrases"

Answer (score 1):

You read your entire file into `contents` for each word. Since you never restore the file pointer to the start of the file, after the first `read` it only stores an empty string.

Fix by reading the file only *once*.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    for word in phrases:
        count = contents.count(word)
        print(word, count)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `count = contents.count(word)`?